# SP2 install on A\P fail-over cluster for SQL2008 & Win2008 - How to?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, installation, cluster

Any recommendations and any known issues with installing SP2 for SQL2008 on Win2008 fail-over Active\Passive Cluster?  And the best procedure to get this done with minimum downtime?  Replication and Service-Broker also running and Distributor is separate instance and clustered.

Known issues?
Risks?
Roll-out & Back-out plan?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be any issues.  The install is pretty easy.

Install on your passive node.  Failover the cluster, then install on the node which is now passive.

The distributor can be patched later without issue.

Comment: Thanks Denny.  I've found the following link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958734 do you mean you have to remove the node from the list of possible owners before you patch it?  As I understand, even when you run it on the passive node, it still will connect to the SQL instance and make the changes to the instance, i.e. system table changes etc?